# How to find conflict between a shelveset and a branch in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, shelveset

A shelveset I've created has conflicts with a branch. I'm able to see the shelveset on Azure Devops, on a link like http://blah:8080/tfs/blah2/blah3/_versionControl/shelveset?ss=blah4%3BCORP%5Cblah5 , but I can't see how to visualize what conflicts there are between the shelveset and a branch.

Is it possible to view the conflicts, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio, you can click **Pending Changes** in Team Explorer and click **Resolve Conflicts**. Then the resolve conflicts page will be displayed and you can choose compare to view conflicts there. Please check below screenshot.
[image]

You can also go click **Actions**, select **Find Shelvesets**, double click your shelveset. And right click on the files under **Changes to Unshelve** and choose **compare with latest version**, which will compare the files diffs with the latest version in server.

[image]

Then you can refer to [this microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/resolve-team-foundation-version-control-conflicts?view=azure-devops) to resolve the conflicts.

Hope above helps.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to do it just using the online web server without having to open visual studio.

Comment: It is impossible to view the conflicts in web server currently.  You can [suggest a new feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) request to Microsoft Team regarding this issue.